# How do I read a .txt file and store certain lines as a list of lists as variables? [Python]

Tags: python, list

If for example I am given a chemistry experiment tutorial, and the materials list is as follows:

```
9 mL water
20 L acid
```

How can I store the materials as the list of lists as [[9, "mL", "water"], [20, "L", "acid"]].

Comment: This is a relatively straight forward problem.  (Read file line by line, store lines in a list, look at the strings in the list and split them, store in another list, etc.)  There may be fancier ways of doing it, but that's all there is to it at the core.  Is there anything in particular that you're having trouble with?

Comment: In the future please try and make a minimal effort to show you've tried something.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    splitted = [line.split() for line in f]
result = [[int(words[0])] + words[1:] for words in splitted]
```

If the numbers are not always integers, use `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: Note, this doesn't _quite_ give the result that OP wants.  It's a pretty simple modification to get there, but I'm a bit wary of just handing out code when we don't even know what part of the problem OP is struggling with...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a strip split with splitlines:

```
s = """9 mL water 
       20 L acid"""

print [r.strip().split(' ') for r in s.splitlines()]
```

**Result:**

```
[['9', 'mL', 'water'], ['20', 'L', 'acid']]
```